# C#, get object indexes from List, by multiple conditions using Linq

Tags: c#, list, linq

linq expressions is to complex for me when i need to do complex searches over list.

let's say i have List

```
public class Object {
    var length;
    var height;
    var depth;
}
```

How to filter objects id by max length, if there are more than one index, then filter by max width, if there are more than one index, then filter by   max depth, if there more then one index return first one.

i found max values:

```
float maxWidth = boxes.Max(x => x.width);
float maxHeight = boxes.Max(x => x.height);
float maxDepth = boxes.Max(x => x.depth);
```

then i used for loop to get values. And it's ok, but after each loop i have to create another list to get another value and etc.

```
private GameObject largestSurfaceBox()
{

    //find max length.width, height box
    float maxWidth = boxes.Max(x => x.GetComponent<Box>().dimensions.x);
    List<GameObject> maxWidthBoxes = new List<GameObject>();

    for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Count; i++) {
        if (System.Math.Abs(boxes[i].GetComponent<Box>().dimensions.x - maxWidth) < float.Epsilon) {
            maxWidthBoxes.Add(boxes[i]);
        }
    }

    float maxHeight = maxWidthBoxes.Max(x => x.GetComponent<Box>().dimensions.y);
    List<GameObject> maxHeightBoxes = new List<GameObject>();

    for (int i = 0; i < maxWidthBoxes.Count; i++) {
        if (System.Math.Abs(maxWidthBoxes[i].GetComponent<Box>().dimensions.y - maxHeight) < float.Epsilon) {
            maxHeightBoxes.Add(boxes[i]);
        }
    }

    List<GameObject> maxDepthBoxes = new List<GameObject>();
    float maxDepth = maxHeightBoxes.Max(x => x.GetComponent<Box>().dimensions.z);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxHeightBoxes.Count; i++) {
        if (System.Math.Abs(maxHeightBoxes[i].GetComponent<Box>().dimensions.z - maxDepth) < float.Epsilon) {
            maxDepthBoxes.Add(boxes[i]);
        }
    }

    return maxDepthBoxes[0];
}
```

How to do that elegant linq way with if statements if possible?

Comment: Please correct your examples before posting. Make sure they will compile if someone will copy-paste to his editor.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Do he actually wanted to ask about `OrderBy`? I guess he was asking about something like `GroupBy`. Edit: If he will order by those 3 conditions and take first one (or last), it will be the same.

Comment: That is not a [mcve]. It isn't complete. Your `Object` class **still** doesn't compile. Where did the `boxes` variable come from? You didn't specify sample inputs or expected outputs.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Your method is called largestSurfaceBox, but what you are doing does not provide you a box with largest surface because that box does not necessarily have largest width. You need to calculate surface of each box and select maximum

Comment: @Slava i can't do that because priority: 1. length, 2.width 3.depth.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for "MaxBy" with multiple conditions. There are few possible options using LINQ extensions. The simple and probably most inefficient is to order and get the first or last item :

```
GameObject result = boxes.OrderBy(x => x.width)
                          .ThenBy(x => x.height)
                          .ThenBy(x => x.depth)
                          .LastOrDefault();
```

---

Another option is to implement [custom comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) on your class so that you can do just `boxes.Max()`,
or use class that already implements it such as `Tuple` (results in Exception if collection is empty) :

```
GameObject result = boxes.Max(x => Tuple.Create(x.width, x.height, x.depth, x)).Item4;
```

The above is also not the most efficient, as it creates a `Tuple` for each item, but will probably be fast enough. Most efficient should be a single `for` loop to get the max item without LINQ.

Comment: MoreLinq's `MaxBy` may be of interest here.

Comment: @Slai You'd just use three `MaxBy` calls (width, then height, then depth) .

Comment: `MaxBy` has returned multiple values for a while now. https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/issues/328